# do something after whole foreach loop is done

Tags: php, loops, foreach

In this code I have a for each loop that goes trough all the results from the array then looks of the user input is equal to that which for now is `$testsubject` after that it checks if the voucher code is not expired and then it needs to calculate the discount to the price `$testamount`

echo's

[image]

I have this foreach loop and I want that it to first loops trough all the items in the array and then if `$testsubject is equal to one of them go check the next thing and if none of them are equal then show the last echo once.

so basically if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) is true stop the for each and go check the next if statement and if it is not true then show the last echo once "this needs to only show when there are no results"

*index.php*

```
function display()
{
$arrContextOptions=array(
  "ssl"=>array(
    "verify_peer"=>false,
    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
  ),
); 

$getVoucherList = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=list_vouchers&api_key=yourkey&resource_id=110556";
$cleanVoucherList = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getVoucherList);
$voucherlist = file_get_contents("$cleanVoucherList", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
$voucherList = json_decode($voucherlist, true);
$testsubject = "TESTVOUCHER-B";
$testamount = "5,00";
$doesvoucherexists = false;

foreach($voucherList['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr){
  if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) {
       $doesvoucherexists = true;
        if (date("Y-m-d") <= $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date']) {
          echo "this code can be used <br>";
          echo $testamount - $testVoucherArr['discount_value'] . "<br>";
      }else{
        echo "this code is expired";
      };

         break;
   }
}
if ($doesvoucherexists === false) {
      echo "this needs to only show when there are no results <br>";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   display();
}}
```

Comment: Please mention the issue you are facing.

Comment: I don't see where an issue here. You want some code to run RIGHT after a foreach? put it right below the foreach???

Comment: You've explained well the result you expect, but you haven't explained how the current code fails to give that result. What is the exact result of the current code.

Comment: the issue i have is that if the voucher in ``$testsubject is equal to the one in the array it still shows `echo "this needs to only show when there are no results <br>";` because it is not equal to the other 2 things in the array

Comment: I want that if `$testsubject` is equal to somthing in the array stop searching in the rest of the array and if it is not equal to one of the things in the array show that but only 1 time

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean @Goose

Comment: You need to move the `if ($doesvoucherexists === false) {` outside the foreach loop

Comment: now it does not echo anything I update the php @DimitrisFilippou

Comment: @berto can you update your post to show me what you tried?

Comment: I updated the php @DimitrisFilippou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you wanna do you have to move the

```
if ($doesvoucherexists === false) {
```

outside the foreach loop.

also you have a syntax error with an extra `;` after the else `}` closing bracket

Tell me if code below is working for you

```
function display()
{
    $arrContextOptions = array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
        ) ,
    );
    $getVoucherList = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=list_vouchers&api_key=yourkey&resource_id=110556";
    $cleanVoucherList = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getVoucherList);
    $voucherlist = file_get_contents("$cleanVoucherList", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    $voucherList = json_decode($voucherlist, true);
    $testsubject = "TESTVOUCHER-B";
    $testamount = "5,00";
    $doesvoucherexists = false;
    foreach($voucherList['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr) {
        if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) {
            $doesvoucherexists = true;
            if (date("Y-m-d") <= $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date']) {
                echo "this code can be used <br />";
                echo $testamount - $testVoucherArr['discount_value'] . "<br />";
            }
            else {
                echo "this code is expired";
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    if ($doesvoucherexists === false) {
        echo "this needs to only show when there are no results <br />";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    display();
}
```